# Issue printing values from a Json array

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to print values from a JSON database into a 2 seperate div tags but I keep getting a syntax error thrown at me

```js
var response;
var urlstring = "http://dev.xxxxxxx.com/llp/n.php?grade=3&subject=math&state=NJ";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#math").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: urlstring,
      type: 'GET',
      error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
        alert("no connection");
      },
      timeout: 60000,
      success: function(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.error.length; i++) {
          '<ul>'
          $('<li>' + response.error[i].LessonName + '</li>').appendTo("#listoftopics").trigger('create');
          for (var x = 0; x < response.error[i].no_of_questions.length; x++) {
            $("Locked Questions : " + " " + response.error[i].no_of_questions[x].Locked + " " + "Unlocked Questions :" + " " + response.error[i].no_of_questions[x].Unlocked + '<br/>' + '<hr>').appendTo("#questNo");

          }
          '</ul>'
        }
      }

    });

  });

})
```

```html
<div id="listoftopics" style="width:100%;">
  - List of subjects
</div>
<div id="questNo" style="width:100%;">
  - Locked Questions
</div>
```

My problem is it prints only the first item in loop and fires an error

Comment: 'and fires an error' of unknown type and unknown value\

Comment: `for(){ '<ul>' $...` this can't possibly be correct

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 1. json is an array, not a database. 2. have you tried debugging with the console all the errors you are getting? your code is full of errors. 3. can you explain what are you trying to get and what is the issue you cannot solve?

Comment: the error report is " Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Comment: I am trying to Print out a list that looks like this <br/> English Language <br/> Locked Question : 22 Unlocked Questions : 20